# Can I read out this 10V load cell with the 5V OpenScale board?

Tags: analog, load, load-cell, sparkfun

For a robotics project in which I want to build a kite flying robot I want to measure the pull force on the rope connected to the kite. To measure this pull force I bought [this load cell](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/strain-gauge-pressure-sensor-S-load-cell-electronic-scale-sensor-Weighing-Sensor-10KG-20KG-50KG-100KG/1083523348.html) (which measures up to 500kg) and to not make things too complicated I bought [this Sparkfun OpenScale board](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/openscale-applications-and-hookup-guide) which can be used to read out load cells using USB. Below you see an example image from the Sparkfun Website showing the OpenScale board connected to a load cell:

[image]

The [load cell I bought](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/strain-gauge-pressure-sensor-S-load-cell-electronic-scale-sensor-Weighing-Sensor-10KG-20KG-50KG-100KG/1083523348.html) hasn't been delivered yet (takes a month!) but in the description I now read:

> For the bridge voltage:Recommended 10 VDC (standard signal 12V 24V)

I'm not sure what the "bridge voltage" is but the OpenScale board is powered by USB, which I guess means it's 5 Volts.

Seeing the image above I suppose the load cell should be powered through the OpenScale board. But if the openScale board is 5 Volts and the load cell needs 10 Volts I guess that can become a problem. So I plugged in the OpenScale board into my computer (with USB), took out my multimeter and measured the voltage on the Load Cell connectors from the OpenScale board. To my surprise it doesn't give any voltage in any combination of the connectors.

So I now wonder about a couple things:

1. How can the load cell be powered through the OpenScale board if it does't give any voltage?
2. If the OpenScale board is indeed 5V and the load cell I bought indeed needs 10V, will this be a problem? Can I combine my load cell with the OpenScale board?
3. If the load cell cannot be powered by the OpenScale board, is it possible to power the load cell from an external power source and still read it out using the OpenScale board?

All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Addressing your questions in reverse order.

- 3) From the documentation for the OpenScale board, I note the following.

  > "When the report rate is above 500ms OpenScale will automatically turn off the power to the load cell between readings. This saves power and limits the amount of localized heating of the strain gauges."

  Until correctly configured, the board will not apply power, and even when it does, a 500ms pulse may not be enough time for the DMM to give a stable reading.
- 2) The design of the load cell is passive, using a circuit called the Wheatstone bridge consisting of four resistors. It will perform perfectly fine at a lower voltage, but your measurements may vary slightly from the manufacturer's specifications (it is likely they test their product during manufacture at 10 volts).
- 1) Based on the design of the OpenScale, I would not recommend using an external power source. The voltage supplied to the load cell is also used as the reference voltage for the analogue to digital converter in the HX711 ASIC. By using another power source you will reduce measurement accuracy and may damage the IC. Unless your load cell has a very low resistance (measure between the 'red' and 'green' wires or equivalent) of less than 50 ohms or so, you should have no problem driving it with the OpenScale. The specifications of the load cell in your link give a resistance of 700 ohms which should work well.

Answer (score 0):

You can normally power load cells at lower voltages than the typical value specified. The signal out will be proportionally lower so you need to take this into account. It should work fine if the output is 5 volts. I've used 10 volt pressure sensors (they have a load cell inside) at 3 volts and it wasn't a problem.

I can't help on why the excitation voltage isn't on the pins though. Maybe this needs to be set up via USB or, maybe your meter was on AC!